# Bluetooth notification code for android

Tags: android, bluetooth

im working on my final project for my collage and im stuck looking for Bluetooth notification code for android.i need the code to notify me whenever my Bluetooth is turned on or off

Comment: did u try doing a google search for this?

Comment: yeah i googled it but nothing turned up

Answer (score 2):

```
OK then do it like that when you bluetooth is on or off


private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

int icon = R.drawable.nishansahib1;        // icon from resources
            CharSequence tickerText = "SatShreeAkal";              // ticker-text
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
            //Context context = getApplicationContext();      // application Context
            CharSequence contentTitle = "";  // message title
//          

            CharSequence contentText= "YPUR BLUETOOTH IS ON OR OFF";      // message text
            final int NOTIF_ID = 1234;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, your classname);//if u want to call a class

            notificationIntent.putExtra("DISPLAY",contentText);//if u want to pass intent
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            NotificationManager notofManager = (NotificationManager)context. getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // the next two lines initialize the Notification, using the configurations above
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notofManager.notify(NOTIF_ID,notification);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add broadcast receivers in your code to receive once bluetooth is switched on or off in your activity class. for your reference :

```
    public void onCreate() {
...
    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new  IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter3);
 }

//The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
       ... //Device found
    }
    else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
       ... //Device is now connected
    }
    else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
       ... //Done searching
    }
    else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
       ... //Device is about to disconnect
    }
    else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
       ... //Device has disconnected
    }           
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code but what i need it to do is put a statement in the notification bar saying that the Bluetooth in on or off or is in-use

Comment: ok then once you came to know is it on or off you can add the notification status .. right?? or you don't know how to add notification bar itself ??

Comment: actually we're being taught about the basics on our 4th year.so now we basically have to depend on the net for codes and info